# Ajax call activate after submit in edit-tags.php page

Tags: categories, ajax, forms

Is there a proper way to activate a ajax call in wordpress in the edit category page after the submit is pressed?

Comment: What ajax call and for what purpose do you mean?

Comment: Basically I know how to get the ajax call to work but its calling it everytime i refresh the page so I want to only call it after I have pressed the submit button in the category edit page in the backend.

Comment: Again, what ajax call? Something from core? From your custom code? What performs it?